# Should the id field of a JPA entity be considered in equals and hashCode?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, equals

I hit a problem when writing tests for a database application using JPA2 and EclipseLink:

I add some entity to a database, retrieve it later and want to compare it to an instance  which has the values I expect to confirm that the addition worked as I intended.

First I wrote something like

```
assertEquals(expResult, dbResult);
```

which failed, because I can't really know the value of `id` field, which is generated by the database and therefore `dbResult` differs from `expResult` which I created with `new` and populated manually.

I see two options:

- Either I remove the `id` field from `equals` and `hashCode` so that the comparison is only based on the "real values". I don't know if this causes problems in the database or elsewhere, though.
- Or I write my tests to explicitly check every field except `id` manually.

What should I do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might find a lot of controversy about this one. My stance is that you absolutely don't use a database primary key for anything in your application. It should be completely invisible. Identify your objects in your application by some other property or combination of properties.

On the "testing persistence operations" front, what you really want is probably to check that the fields were saved and loaded correctly and maybe that the primary key got assigned some value when you saved it. This probably isn't a job for the equals method at all.

Comment: might find a lot of controversy?  That's optimistic.

Answer (score 8):

Relying on database generated Ids in your `equals` and `hashCode` implementation is not advisable. You ought to rely on the truly unique/semi-unique attributes of your classes in checking for equality, and in generating the hashcode values. The [Hibernate documentation](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode) has an extensive page that discusses this, and the facts therein are applicable to more or less every JPA provider.

The underlying reason for using business keys over database generated values in your `equals` and `hashCode` implementation is that the JPA provider must actually issue a `SELECT` after persisting the entity in the database. If you compare objects using the database generated Ids, then you will end up having an equality test that fails in the following scenarios:

- If `E1` and `E2` are entities of class E (that verifies equality using database generated Ids), then if `E1` and `E2` will be equal if they haven't been stored in the database yet. This is not what you want, especially if want to store `E1` and `E2` in some `Set` before persistence. This is worse if the attributes of `E1` and `E2` possess different values; the `equals` implementation would prevent two significantly different entities from being added to a `Set`, and the `hashCode` implementation will give you a `O(n)` lookup time when entities are looked up from a `HashMap` using the primary key.
- If `E1` is a managed entity that has been persisted, and `E2` is an entity that has not been persisted, then the equality test would deem that `E1` != `E2` in the scenario where all the attribute values of `E1` and `E2` (except for the Ids) are similar. Again, this is probably not what you want, especially if you want to avoid duplicate entities in the database that differ only in their database generated Ids.

The `equals` and `hashCode` implementations therefore ought to use business keys, in order to exhibit consistent behavior for both persisted and unpersisted entities.

Comment: "Hibernate documentation" link gives 404

Answer (score 7):

From the book Hibernate in Action, its recommended to defined a *business key* and test equality on that.  A business key is "a property, or some combination of properties, that is unique for each instance with the same database identity."  In other areas it says to not use the id as one of those properties, and don't use values in collections.

Answer (score 1):

I would write my test to explicitly check for fields. To make this easy, before performing the assertEqual test, I will set the id of both the expected and actual result to the same predefined value  and then use the normal equals method.

Removing ID from equals is not justifiable, just because testing is slightly difficult. You are foregoing serious performance benefits and also code integrity.

Comment: What are the performance and integrity problems associated with not considering the id? Wouldn't checking for a database id be the same thing as using `Object#hashCode` in my `equals` and `hashCode` methods?

Comment: Lets say that you have project entities. You have to send a list of unique projects from your service layer. Now there is a possibility that a faulty equals will consider two unique records as the same record. Having ID  reduces this problem. Also the solution is not scalable, we have to update our equals method, if we decide to change what makes an object unique.

Comment: Having an ID that is guaranteed to be unique is a perfect for hashing. We are guaranteed to avoid Hash collisions. Otherwise, the quality of hashing becomes a function of whether, we considered all attributes that should be unique and ignored all attributes that are not.

Comment: We have a different (from the database ID) "business" ID which is unique. Does this solve the problem?

Comment: Yes,I think so, as long as, it is guaranteed to be unique. (Sorry for all the typos in my previous comments. My excuse is sleep deprivation :) ).